# React How can i make new array when i choose some item from picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I thinking for few days but cant realize how can i make it. I have 4 json data and 4 picker.
Its for  city,district,village,neirborhood. In first i must choose city then in second picker it must show district about that i choose city. When i choose district from picker third one must show villages about that district. And neirborhood is same too. In that json datas they have some connection. Like city json have ' id-name' district have 'id-cityid-name' village have 'id-districtid-name' neirborhood have 'id-villageid-name' Like that. But i cant figure out how can i make it. Its my codes I really stuck with that hardly i need some help please. Thank you! My codes :

Elements :

```
const DropdownElements = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: "Şehir",
    placeholder: "Şehir Seçiniz",
    apiUrl: "https://api.npoint.io/995de746afde6410e3bd",
    type: "city",
    selecteditem: "",
    data : [],
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: "İlçe",
    placeholder: "İlçe Seçiniz",
    apiUrl: "https://api.npoint.io/fc801dbd3fc23c2c1679", 
    type: "district",
    selecteditem: "",
    data : [],
  },

  {
    key: 3,
    title: "Köy",
    placeholder: "Köy Seçiniz",
    apiUrl: "https://api.npoint.io/72cf025083b70615b8bb",
    type: "village",
    selecteditem: "",
    data : [],
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    title: 'Mahalle',
    placeholder:'Mahalle Seçiniz',
    apiUrl: 'https://api.npoint.io/0c04c63923c8ca4e117b',
    type: 'neighborhood',
  selecteditem: "",
    data : [],
  },


];
```

Component :

```
    const PickerCompanent = (props) => {
  const [xdata, setData] = useState([]);
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState([]);
  let x;
  let y = [];
  // data.filter((a) => a.il_id == "3");
  useEffect(() => {
    props.datasource.then(setData);

    switch (props.type) {
      case "city":
        x = props.selecteditem;
        setNewData(xdata);
        break;
      case "district":
        y = xdata.filter((element) => {
          if (props.selecteditem === element.id) {
            return element;
          }
        });

        break;
      case "village":
        console.log("village");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("def");
        break;
    }
  }, [props.datasource]);

  return (
    <Select
      showSearch
      style={{ width: 200, marginLeft: 15 }}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      optionFilterProp="children"
      onChange={(x) => props.onChange(x)}
      onFocus={props.onFocus()}
      datasource={xdata}
      onSearch={props.onSearch()}
      filterOption={(input, option) =>
        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      }
    >
      {xdata &&
        xdata.map((x) => {
          return (
            <Select.Option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
              {x.name}{" "}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        })}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

My App :

```
const App = () => {
  const [dataap, setDataAp] = useState([]);
  const [idhold, setIDHold] = useState();

  const filldata = (value) => {};

  function onChange(value) {
    setIDHold(value);
    console.log(value);
  }

  const getData = (value, type) => {
    return fetch(value)
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => {
        return y;
      });
  };

  function onFocus() {}

  function onSearch(val) {}

  return (
    <Space>
      {DropdownElements.map((x) => {
        return (
          <PickerCompanent
            showSearch
            selecteditem={idhold}
            key={x.key}
            placeholder={x.placeholder}
            type={x.type}
            datasource={getData(x.apiUrl)}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onChange={(z) => onChange(z)}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onSearch={onSearch}
          ></PickerCompanent>
        );
      })}
    </Space>
  );
};
```

If you need i can give my teamviewer or skype too. I really need that help thanks for replies!

Sandbox : codesandbox.io/s/runtime-monad-vxit

Comment: Make a codesandbox please.

Comment: @MannyAlvarado sure! I will make it and edit comment in few minutes!

Comment: Also you want to repopulate the district according to the city you select, and the village according to the district you select?

Comment: @MannyAlvarado brother i cant codesandbox because i using Ant Design codes cant u connect my computer via teamviewer or something like that ?

Comment: @MannyAlvarado Yes. I need do it exactly u said.

Comment: Yes I see you're fetching from somewhere. I'll make something simple in codesandbox and share it here

Comment: @MannyAlvarado I will appreciete a lot brother really. I really stuck on it for few days.

Comment: @MannyAlvarado brother thanks for your codesandbox! I trying check now but i made codesandbox too. Can u check on mine too please if you are free ? My sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-monad-vxitx

Comment: Your API is not working. I mean it works, but it always returns the same values

Comment: @MannyAlvarado becouse i cant filter them to make new data when i choose city or what thats why it have a lot value like that and cant change its my problem that i cant solved and need help

Comment: The API should give you filtered results. That shouldn't be a frontend problem. Good luck buddy!

Comment: @MannyAlvarado Thank you for all brother!

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-moore-7w105?file=/src/App.js

Select CityTwo to see the dropdown update.

You need a switch. Updating arrays inside state is tricky. You can't populate or push anything in an array that's in state. Update your array outside state, THEN update state.

Comment: brother thanks for your codesandbox! I trying check now but i made codesandbox too. Can u check on mine too please if you are free ? My sandbox : codesandbox.io/s/runtime-monad-vxitx